# How to get the data of specific date when the Datetime is stored in string

Tags: sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I've a table named `datatransaction` where the datetime is stored in string format (example: 1/28/2021 4:25:00 PM, 1/28/2021 4:30:00 PM and so on). The column name is `Insertdate`. Now if I want to get all the data of 28th January, how can I use the `where` clause in SQL Server? As there are multiple data of 28th Jan consisting different time.

Comment: Convert it to a `DATE`

Comment: You have to convert it to a `datetime` datetype and then use that in your `where` clause. Unfortunately that is costly as its not possible to use indexes then. Ideally you would change your column datatype to `datetime2` - you should never store a datetime as a string. There are lots of example of how to do this on this site.

Comment: _28th January_ This is a day, not a date. Did you mean 28th January 2021? That is a date. Don't assume, be precise, develop good habits.